# LibreOffice vs. LibreOffice Vanilla

Tags: macos, libreoffice

What is the difference between LibreOffice, as available for download from the [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) web site, and LibreOffice Vanilla, as available from the macOS AppStore? And how do current version numbers compare?

I guess downloading an image from that web site is okay, but then macOS asks me to confirm the image as obtained from a mirror site with an unfamiliar name. This still makes sense on a technical level, but frankly I'd prefer to install via the AppStore, esp. since the admin password is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice Vanilla is almost identical to LibreOffice Fresh. The only difference is that when downloading Fresh, the website asks for a donation. AFAIK there are some policies in App Store which doesn't allow asking for money in application listing. Since the money from donations are important for LibreOffice development the Vanilla version includes a donation link (which should be the only difference).

See https://www.collaboraoffice.com/community-en/libreoffice-vanilla-mac-app-store/ and https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/

Comment: The folks from Collabra apparently do not mention though that they do not only raise (much-needed) financial support via the pop-up window but also by a 10.99 € fee (in my location) for LibreOffice Vanilla in the macOS AppStore.

Answer (score 5):

The Document Foundation Wiki has a page about [LibreOffice Vanilla for Mac](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/LibreOffice_Vanilla_for_Mac), which explains the differences.

There are some differences in functionality. LibreOffice Vanilla for Mac omits some Java-based features. The upshot is that Base cannot use the HSQLDB engine, and is lacking some reporting features. Java-based extensions won't work either.

The wiki page includes a detailed list of build flags used to compile the Collabora versions, which provide further detail. (Caveat: it's a wiki, so this may not be up to date.)

Note that Collabora's post [LibreOffice Vanilla: Fresh from the community to your Mac](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/community-en/libreoffice-vanilla-mac-app-store/) does not mention these functional differences.

Answer (score 3):

I should add, at time of writing, LibreOffice Base does not fully support M1 Silicone Macs, while Vanilla does.

```
LibreOffice:

  Version:  7.1.0.3
  Obtained from:    Identified Developer
  Last Modified:    29/01/21, 3:40 AM
  Kind: Intel
  Signed by:    Developer ID Application: The Document Foundation (7P5S3ZLCN7), Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
  Location: /Applications/LibreOffice.app
```

Another source: https://isapplesiliconready.com/?apps=LibreOffice%20Vanilla,LibreOffice